# Record Label Information through the API

Tags: beatsmusic

I was thinking about playing with the Beats API and I was really hoping to sort music by record label.  I'm not seeing anything for labels in the documentation.  Does anyone know where that info might be stored in the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available through the API.